# Unable to "send keys" or "input text" to a field in shadow dom

Tags: selenium, robotframework, shadow-dom

I have an issue automating a new login form we are using.   The login fields for username and password are in the shadow dom.   I can access them using the following code in Selenium/robotframework)

`Execute Javascript    document.querySelector("body > div.main >  div.auth-component login").shadowRoot.querySelector("#username")`

I can even "input" the username/password using

`Execute Javascript    document.querySelector("body > div.main >  div.auth-component > login").shadowRoot.querySelector("#username").value="username"`

The problem is that this doesn't actually "type" the data into the field, so as far as the form is concerned, nothing has been entered into the field, so the login button never activates.

Is there a way to "send keys" to an input field in the shadow dom, not using the .value() ability?

Dan

[image: shadowdom tree]

Comment: Can you show the structure you want to navigate?

Comment: Here's a screenshot.  I have no issue navigating and verifying the elements in the shadow dom exist, and can click things in the shadow dom. the issue is that while assigning the value does put the username/password in the field, it's not actually typing them so the form doesn't recognize the values are there.  I need a way to use the Input Text or Send Keys to the field to enter the data into the fields in the shadow dom.

Comment: Send an Enter key to the input; you might also need https://web.dev/more-capable-form-controls/

Comment: How do I send an enter key to that field?  if I could send keys, I would just send the username.  I can't use any of the standard selenium/robotframework commands like Input Text or Press keys, since the field is under the shadow dom.   Is there a javascript command to send a key or keys to an input field?

Comment: I'm not really experienced with Selenium, but to me it seems that `document.querySelector("body > div.main >  div.auth-component ").querySelector("#username").value="username"` is worth a try.

Comment: As I noted above, that is what I've done. The problem is that that command just "assigns" the value to the field;  it appears in the field on the page, but since it's not actually "typed" in, the data is not really there (not entered as it would be using an input text command).     I need a way to actually INPUT the data into the field, not simply assign the value to the field using that command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after going down a javascript rabbit hole, was able to get this to work.

So, after using this in Selenium/Robotframework to assign the value to the input field:

`Execute Javascript    document.querySelector("body > div.main > section.auth-section > div.auth-component > login").shadowRoot.querySelector("#username").value='username'`

I then had to use another command to trigger the input event listener so the page knew a value had been entered into the field:

`Execute Javascript    document.querySelector("body > div.main > section.auth-section > div.auth-component > login").shadowRoot.querySelector("#username").dispatchEvent(new Event('input',{'bubbles':true}))`

Did the same for the password field, and all is right with the world.  :)

Dan